# How to extract predefined pattern from a string?

Tags: javascript

Given the following string:

```
"<head></head><body>{"filesize":55312,"success":false,"msg":"incorrect-captcha-sol"}<div firebugversion="1.5.4" style="display: none;" id="_firebugConsole"></div></body>"
```

I need to extract the JSON string as follows:

```
{"filesize":55312,"success":false,"msg":"incorrect-captcha-sol"}
```

How should I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 json = str.match(/(\{[^}]+\})/)[1];
```

Comment: Hello,

May you tell me why we have to use [1] here?

I debug the code and it seems that
str.match(/(\{[^}]+\})/)[0] is same as str.match(/(\{[^}]+\})/)[1]?

Thank you

Comment: was my mistake :P... the match function returns an array of the elements that matched the regular expresion... because there was only one match it didn't matter, you can even delete the []
you might want to look at this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Comment: Hello pleasedontbelong,

it is strange that the first element of the returned array contains the same value as that of second element.

When I search Google, I also see lots of example with [1].
Really have no clues here.

Thank you

Comment: The first element contains the full match, the second element is the capture group. In this case they are the same but they may not be. Note: because they are the same you might as well just do: `/\{[^}]+\}/`. But they may not be, for example if your intention is to instead match the value of filesize then: `/\{[^}]*filesize":[^}]*(\d+)[^}]*\}/` will match the whole json string as the first element and the string `"55312"` as the second element.

Answer (score 1):

```
json = str.match(/([^<]+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression like

```
({[^}]+})
```

would work.

Try it out using [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).